# How to replace sets in Redis

Tags: redis

I have a use case where I have to update sets in Redis every one hour.

Suppose the sets were created with following commands

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd k1 m11 m12 m13 m14
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd k2 m21 m22 m23 m24
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd k3 m31 m32 m33
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd k4 m41
(integer) 1
```

After 1 hour, I want to update the data to

```
k1 = {m11, m13, m15}
k2 = {m21, m25}
k5 = {m51, m52}
```

I found that this can be done using Redis transactions

```
multi
del k1
sadd k1 m11 m13 m15
exec

multi
del k2
sadd k2 m21 m25
exec

multi
del k5
sadd k5 m51 m52
exec
```

But now `k3` and `k4` are still present in Redis. If I don't remove them, they pile up over time. I am solving this by adding 2 hour expiry to every key.

But found one problem with the above approach.Transactions in Redis don't have roll back if a command fails after `exec`.

So, if `del k1` passed and `sadd k1 m11 m13 m15` failed, k1 will be removed from Redis entirely. I would prefer to have old data instead of having nothing.

Is there a way to avoid deleting a key when `sadd` fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The possible problem you describe is not that probable, if `del k1` is executed then the probability of `sadd k1 m11 m13 m15` being executed is pretty high.
2. There is a solution that involves  [SUNIONSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/sunionstore/) and [SINTERSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/sinterstore/).

```
sadd k1 m11 m12 m13 m14 // Setup

multi
sadd kt m11 m13 m15     // Create a temporary key
sunionstore k1 k1 kt    // Store union of k1/kt in k1
sinterstore k1 k1 kt    // Store intersection of k1/kt in k1
del kt                  // Clean kt
exec
```

You have to note that :

- It can be pretty CPU intensive/long depending on the length of the sets because of the time complexity of these commands
- sunionstore and sinterstore commands are interchangeable, the order depends on what you want to optimise. The order I gave is to have the less data loss (your requirement) and the other is to optimize time complexity (the O(N+M) command being executed first) but at the cost of some possible data loss.